# How to use Acrobat plugin from C++ application with InterAppCommunication

Tags: c++, pdf, plugins, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

My app needs to open a pdf in Acrobat and apply a plugin. I searched the internet for solutions but I didn't find at least one example.

What I did: I managed to develop the plugin, integrate it in Acrobat and open pdfs in Acrobat.

Now I just need to apply it and I'm stuck. Any help?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried out some methods from Acrobat SDK documentation and I found the answer: you can call the plugin with:

`acrobatApp -> MenuItemExecute( "itemName");`

where `itemName` is the name you set in plugin handshake method.